# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider, while calling service in controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am trying to use service in my controller and it is giving

> Error: $injector:unpr
>   Unknown Provider
>   Unknown provider: getAuthorProvider <- getAuthor <- PostController

Here is what I am doing:

app.js

```
angular.module('app',[
    'ui.router',
    'app.controllers'
    ])
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('homePage',{
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'mainView': {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'PostController'
            }
        },      
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}]);
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('app.controllers',[
            'app.directives'
        ]).controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$http','getAuthor' , function($scope,$http,getAuthor) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/blog'
            }).then(function (response){
                $scope.currentPage=1;
                $scope.pageSize=10;
                //console.log(response);
                $scope.posts = response.data;
                console.log($scope.posts);
                $scope.pageinput = $scope.currentPage;
                $scope.authorName = function(authorId) {
                    getAuthor.getAuthorNameById(authorId,function(response){
                        console.log(response.data);
                        //return response.data;
                    }, function(response){
                        alert('Some errors occurred while communicating with the service. Try again later.');
                    });
                };
                $scope.numberOfPages = function() {
                    return Math.ceil($scope.posts.length / $scope.pageSize);
                };
                $scope.setCurrentPage = function(newValue) {
                    $scope.currentPage = newValue;
                    $scope.pageinput = newValue;
                    $scope.$apply();
                };
                $scope.submitFunc = function() {
                    var temp = $scope.currentPage;
                    if($scope.pageinput >=0 && $scope.pageinput <= $scope.numberOfPages()) {
                        $scope.currentPage = $scope.pageinput;
                        $scope.CurrentPage = $scope.currentPage;
                        setTimeout(window.scrollTo(0,150),2000);
                    }else {

                    }
                }
            },function(error){
                console.log('failed');
            });
        }]);
```

service.js

```
angular.module('app.factories',[
    'LocalStorageModule'
    ]).factory('getAuthor',['Restangular',function(Restangular) {
    function getAuthorNameById(authorId,onSuccess,onError) {
        Restangular.one('api/author/name',authorId).get().then(function(response){
            onSuccess(response);
        }, function(response) {
            onError(response);
        });
    }
}]);
```

I am calling the function **authorName()** in my HTML file as:

```
{{authorName(2)}}
```

as this function should take authorId and return his name. I am not sure where I am getting it wrong and now I am not getting any idea how to set it perfectly.

Comment: Have you included the getAuthor service file in index.html file? Please check.

Comment: @AjuJohn yes I have included the service.js file in the following order: 1) angular.min.js, 2)angular-ui-router.min.js, 3) angular-local-storage.min.js, 4) restangular.min.js, 5) app.js, 6)controllers.js, 7) directives.js, 8) services.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you did not include `app.factories` as a dependency as reported by @charlietfl

in addition you're missing the return statement inside the factory, you're only declaring the function, this could be related to the error.

```
angular.module('app.factories',[
    'LocalStorageModule'
    ]).factory('getAuthor',['Restangular',function(Restangular) {
    function getAuthorNameById(authorId,onSuccess,onError) {
      Restangular.one('api/author/name',authorId).get().then(function(response){
            onSuccess(response);
        }, function(response) {
            onError(response);
        });
    }

    return {
     getAuthorNameById: getAuthorNameById
    }
}]);
```

And move the invocation of `authorName()` inside your controller. 
When you interpolate a function call (as you did in your template, with this syntax `{{authorName(2)}}`) the function will be called each digest cycle.

To answer your question in the comments i'd follow this approach.

```
.directive('handleItem', function(getAuthor){
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
    item: '='
   }
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
     //make the call here 
     getAuthor
     .getAuthorNameById($scope.item.authorId,function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        //return response.data;
     }, function(response){
        alert('Some errors occurred while communicating with the service. 
         Try again later.');
     });
   }
  }
})
```

and in the template something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"> <!--loop over your items-->
  <handle-item item="item"></handle-item>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I included app.factories in controllers.js and restangular in services.js and it worked

Comment: and also returned the result as you mentioned above

Comment: and it's giving me this error: Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop

Comment: return {
        getAuthorNameById : function getAuthorNameById(authorId,onSuccess,onError) {
            Restangular.one('api/author',authorId).get().then(function(response){
                console.log('response'+response.data);
                //return response;
                onSuccess(response);
            }, function(response) {
                onError(response);
            });
        }
    }

Comment: the digest loop most likely is caused by how you're invoking the method. {{authorName(2)}} this will be triggered each digest cycle, try to invoke authorName()  inside your controller

Comment: you saved my day. Is there a way that I can use this function inside my html file. As I am getting a list of posts and then I am iterating it, and then I wanted to passing the post->author to this function to get the author name in the html file

Comment: if you're iterating over something and for each item you want to call that function, you can create a directive with the item as an input and inside the directive call the factory method

Comment: Hey Karim, thanks for the advice, can you suggest how to create the above-mentioned directive as I am totally new to angular, hence I am getting confused.

Comment: Calling authorName(2) in ng-init solved my problem. However, if, there is any better and faster approach for this please do let me know guys

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that module `app.factories` is injected in any of the other modules.

Try:

```
angular.module('app',[
    'ui.router',
    'app.controllers',
    'app.factories'
    ])
```

Also doesn't appear that `Restangular` module is injected anywhere either